# Let $P(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Prove or disprove that $P\circ P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: functions, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

**Let $P(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Prove or disprove that $P\circ P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.**

---

I tried expanding $P(x)=\sum a_ix_i$ and then putting $P(P(k))=0$ assuming that $\nexists$ $r \ni P(r)=0 \forall r\in\mathbb{Z}$. I observed that $P(k)\mid \{\text{co-ef of }x^0\}$. And there's no more progress.

I think that it's not reducible but I cannot prove it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if $P$ is quadratic, then the irreducibility of $P$ implies that of $P\circ P$.  However, I do not know whether this works in general.

Comment: I suspect this is not known in general. See for example [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-06/S0002-9939-01-06258-X/S0002-9939-01-06258-X.pdf) or [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.573.5632&rep=rep1&type=pdf)